# Java 8 Consumer with additional parameters

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, consumer

I want to write a generic DTO updater, which updates some of it's properties. My object looks like this:

```
class Person {
    String firsName;
    String lastName;
    Integer age;
    setter/getter
}
```

I have an enum which defines which fields can be overridden:

```
enum OverriddenType {
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    AGE
}
```

Instead of doing a "hardcoded" setter like this...

```
public void override(Person person, Map<OverriddenType,Object> newValuesForProperties) {
    newValuesForProperties.forEach((type,value)) -> {
        if(type == OverriddenType.FIRST_NAME) {
            person.setFirstName((String)value);
        } else if(type == OverriddenType.LAST_NAME) {
            person.setLastName((String)value);
        } else if(type == OverriddenType.AGE) {
            person.setAge((Integer)value);
        }
    });
}
```

... I would like to use some Java 8 Function/Consumer features to define the setters in each enum. I tried something like this:

```
enum OverriddenType {
    FIRST_NAME(p -> p.setFirstName(???????)),  //don't know what to set here since the value is not here
    LAST_NAME(p -> p.setLastName(???????)),
    AGE(p -> p.setAge(???????));
    
    Consumer<Person> consumer;
    OverriddenType(Consumer<Person> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }
    public Consumer<Person> getConsumer();
}
```

But as you can see I cannot pass the dynamic value here. Also don't know how the logic would look like, but I would imagine something like this:

```
public void override(Person person, Map<OverriddenType,Object> newValuesForProperties) {
    newValuesForProperties.forEach((type,value)) -> 
        type.getConsumer().accept(person, value) // this doesn't exist, but I can imagine some additional parameter passing
    );
}
```

Can you provide me a solution for this? Can it work? I am afraid that the incoming value is a dynamic therefore it won't work for enums..

Comment: Maybe check [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A setter method is a [`BiConsumer<T,U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html), where `T` is the object instance, and `U` is the value.

```java
enum OverriddenType {
    FIRST_NAME((person, value) -> person.setFirsName((String) value)),
    LAST_NAME ((person, value) -> person.setLastName((String) value)),
    AGE       ((person, value) -> person.setAge((Integer) value));

    private final BiConsumer<Person, Object> setter;

    private OverriddenType(BiConsumer<Person, Object> setter) {
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    public void override(Person person, Object value) {
        this.setter.accept(person, value);
    }
}
```

```java
public void override(Person person, Map<OverriddenType, Object> newValuesForProperties) {
    newValuesForProperties.forEach((type, value) -> type.override(person, value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By definition a `Consumer` only ever takes one argument.

Since you need to be passed both the object to manipulate and the new value, you have to use an interface that allows two arguments to be passed. Luckily there's [the `BiConsumer` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) for that.

```
BiConsumer<Person, String> personFirstNameSetter = Person::setFirstName;
```

Note that the use of a method reference here is roughly equivalent to writing `(p, fn) -> p.setFirstName(fn)`.

However, this introduces a slight problem, because you need to know (and specify) the type of the parameter and your enum would like to have mixed types (the first two would return `BiConsumer<Person,String>` and the last one probably `BiConsumer<Person,Integer>`.

Comment: So your answer is that there is a problem with the differing value types, without providing a solution for that problem? Not very useful, then, is it?

Comment: @Andreas: I don't consider accepting `Object` and casting it a viable solution (as whatever is passing in values still needs to know the right type, except now it can't tell them from the argument type). And I don't know enough about OPs problem to provide a better solution. Thank you for your valuable feedback, though.

Comment: Look at the `override()` method in the middle of the question, which shows that the override values comes in as a `Map<OverriddenType, Object>`, making conversion of `Object` to appropriate value type necessary, and OP chose to simply cast the value. The question isn't about casting the value, it's about using a `BiConsumer` registered with the `enum` is lieu of a multi-way `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BiConsumer` which can consume the target object and the new value:

```
enum OverriddenType {
    FIRST_NAME((p, v) -> p.setFirstName(v)),
    LAST_NAME((p, v) -> p.setLastName(v)),
    AGE((p, v) -> p.setAge(v));
    
    BiConsumer<Person> consumer;
    OverriddenType(BiConsumer<Person, Object> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public BiConsumer<Person> getConsumer();
}
```

(If your setter accepts an `Object`, you may even use method references:

```
    OBJECT(Person::setObject)
```

)

Instead of exposing the consumer directly, consider defining a public `assign` or `set` method in your enum and make the consumer invisible to the outside (information hiding):

```
public void assign(final Person target, final Object newValue) {
  this.consumer.accept(target, newValue);
}
```

then call as `FIRST_NAME.assign(person, "new name")`.

Comment: `Bi Consumer` is wrong, since it shouldn't have a space in the name. --- `Person::setFirstName` is wrong, since it takes a `String` parameter, but the `consumer` has `Object` as the value type.

Comment: `Person` doesn't have a `setObject` method. --- `p.setFirstName(v)` will fail to compile, since `v` is `Object`, but parameter to `setFirstName` is `String`.